# Reply/Reply All/Forward buttons not loading the default email template specified in the Lightning Action

Tags: servicecloud

This is happening in the Lightning Case feed. I have created a custom Action for sending an email. On that action I have selected a default email template (it is a lighting email template) to use.

In the case feed, when I load the email composed under the action (image below) the default template loads:
[image]

However, when users click the Reply/Reply All/Forward buttons under an email in the feed (image below), the composer still loads but the email template does not load (ie the composer is just empty)

[image]

I can't find any info on how these Reply/Reply All/Forward buttons work compared to the email action at the top of the feed. Does anyone know if this is working as expected or is there something else I need to configure to get the default email to load?

I believe there is a way of defining default email templates using apex, however I want to avoid that if possible and also not sure it would solve this problem.

Thanks